# Simple code only works in certain editor but not anywhere else

Tags: javascript

Why does the below code only work in the Codecademy.com editor and not in a real browser or jsfiddle? There seem to be no mistakes...

HTML

```
<p id='p1'>Zebras eat bananas</p>
<p id='p2'>That's nonsense</p>
```

With this javascript, #p2 should change automatically when the page has loaded. In the Codecademy editor that's what happens, but [see it not work in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcytpnyn/2/) and also not when I make HTML/js files and run it in my browser.

How can I fix this? Or did they teach me wrong?

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#p2').html("Now it makes sense!");
})
```

Comment: Include jQuery and it will make sense in jsfiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/jcytpnyn/3/

Comment: Use " quotes for property values

Comment: @Johan `"` and `'` or even no quotes at all (in this case) are equivalent.

Comment: @dfsq Yeah, you're right about that single vs double quote. But even no quotes?

Comment: @Johan Quotes are optional if attribute value does not contain spaces, or `"`, `'`, `=`, `>`, `<`, or `\``, characters. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-unquoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dfsq has mentionend, you need to include jQuery to your file, as to your fiddle. You can do this by adding this line before your script:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After that, you can put your code in `<script>` tags:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#p2').html("Now it makes sense!");
})
</script>
```

and you will see that it works.

Your jQuery script should allways be directly before the closing `</body>` tag, so that the DOM is loaded before you try to access it with javascript/jQuery